# How to fix 'CaptureFinger' is not defined error occurred while accepting a biometric input with javascript with mantra MFS100

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, biometrics

I am trying to develop a simple web app that inputs a biometric using mantra mfs100 biometric scanner. I am using react.js for this purpose. I have imported `<script src="jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and `<script src="mfs100.js"></script>` in the head tag provided in the documentation but I am getting

> ERROR [eslint]  src\App.js   Line 20:19:  'CaptureFinger' is not defined
> no-undef ..

on the browser screen just like react shows its errors.
After ignoring the error, it's working fine but still, the error is not resolved.

I have written the following code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

const App = () => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = './mfs100.js';
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

    }, []);

    function capture(fingerImgToDisplay) {
        console.log("hello")
        var quality = 100; //(1 to 100) (recommended minimum 55)
        var timeout = 10; // seconds (minimum=10(recommended), maximum=60, unlimited=0)
        let res = CaptureFinger(quality, timeout);
        console.log(fingerImgToDisplay);
        console.log(res.data.BitmapData);
        $(fingerImgToDisplay).show();
        $('#progress').hide();
        $(fingerImgToDisplay).attr(
            'src',
            'data:image/png;base64,' + res.data.BitmapData
        );

    }

    return (
        <>

            <div className="container">
                <div className="fingerbox">
                    <img
                        id="fingerImg1"
                        className="capturedImg"
                        src="scanning.gif"
                        alt="Scanning"
                    />
                    <br />
                    <button
                        className="btnReadThumbs"
                        id="finger1"
                        onClick={() => capture('#fingerImg1')}
                    >
                        Capture Finger1
                    </button>
                </div>


            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I am expecting that it does not show me this error... please help

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const Mantra = () => {

    const [thumb, setThumb] = useState('');

    function handleMantra() {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var MFS100Request = {
            "Quality": 100,
            "TimeOut": 10
        };
        var raw = JSON.stringify({
            "data": JSON.stringify(MFS100Request)
        });

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };


        fetch('http://localhost:8004/mfs100/capture', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                setThumb('data:image/png;base64,' + result.BitmapData)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }

    return (
        <div>Mantra
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src={thumb} />
            <br />
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => handleMantra()}>Capture</button>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Mantra;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).